# Minimum variance unbiased estimator

Tags: self-study

**A**. Determine the restrictions needed on the $a$'s so that $z=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i$ will be an unbiased estimator $E\left[X\right]$, where $X_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_n$ represents a random sample of $X$.

**Answer:** The $a$'s must sum to one.

**B**. What is the best set of $a$'s to choose from **A** if $z=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i$ is to be an unbiased estimator of $E\left[X\right]$ with *minimum variance*.

**Answer:** $a_i=1/n$.

The first answer I've shown I understand. However I'm a bit stumped as to how to arrive at the answer to part **B**.

**EDIT:** I'm not exactly sure what the question is asking. What I think it's asking is: find $$\left\{a_i:\mathrm{var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i\right)=\frac{1}{n\sigma^2}\right\},$$ where $\sigma^2$ is the expected value of the squared derivative of some arbitrary log likelihood function of $X$ given some parameter $\theta$.

I know that $$\mathrm{var}\left(X\right)=E\left[\left(X-\theta\right)^2\right].$$ How do I compute the variance of $z$?

$\mathrm{var}\left(z\right) = E\left[z^2\right] - \theta^2$.

How do I evaluate $E\left[z^2\right]$ without a density function?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please provide some such context so that we can best help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $X_i$ are iid each with positive finite variance $v$ then $$\text{var}\left(\sum_i a_i X_i\right) = \sum_i \text{var}\left( a_i X_i\right) = \sum_i a_i^2 \text{var}\left( X_i\right) = \sum_i a_i^2 v = v \sum_i a_i^2$$

so you want to minimise $v \sum_i a_i^2$ subject to $\sum_i a_i =1$ (since it has to be unbiased).  You can ignore the positive constant $v$ and deduce this happens when each $a_i=1/n$; for example the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality will do this.

Comment: Why can you pull out $v$? Is it because $v = n\cdot\mathrm{var}\left(X\right)$?

Comment: It is a multiplicative constant equal to $\text{var}\left( X_i\right)$ - I have added an extra step to make this clearer

Comment: Alright maybe I'm being thickheaded here, but what variable am I supposed to minimize with respect to if I'm ignoring the variance?

Comment: You are aiming to minimise $v \sum_i a_i^2$ subject to $\sum_i a_i =1$.  The values of $a_i$ which do this also minimise  $\sum_i a_i^2$ subject to $\sum_i a_i =1$ since $v$ is a positive constant.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. If I write $2v\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=2$, since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=1$ that doesn't help me at all.

Comment: What values of $a_i$ do you think minimise the variance which is $v \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2$? (subject to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=1$)

Comment: I know that $a_i= 1/n$ but only because that's the answer in the book. However, it is not obvious to me how to show that this true. For example, how do I know that $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n$? And there are no restrictions saying that $a_i \notin\mathbb{R}$, so $a_i$ could be negative.

Comment: Suppose two of the $a_i$ are different, say $b$ and $c$. Then the sum of their squares is more the sum of the squares of their averages, i.e. $b^2 +c^2 \ge \left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2$, so (with a fixed sum of the terms) equalising all the terms will minimise the sum of the squares.  You can prove this by looking at  $b^2 +c^2 - \left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{(b-c)^2}{2}$ which is non-negative.

Comment: Hm. I still don't fully understand your reasoning. Can I use the fact that since the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean, and the mean minimizes the variance, then $a_i=1/n$?